# NOtification doesn't appear on Android 8.0 Oreo

Tags: java, android, notifications, android-notifications, android-8.0-oreo

I've read other Stackoverflow articles about notification doesn't appear on Android 8.0 Oreo, but the code still doesn't work on Android Android api 26.

The code is as follows:

```
    public void notification()
{

    //Create Notification Channel
    String channelId = "";
    String name = "volume";
    int id = 0;
    int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH;

    NotificationChannel mChannel = new NotificationChannel(channelId, name, 
importance);
    mChannel.setShowBadge(true);

    //Create Notification Manager
    Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);

    PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
            PendingIntent.getActivity(
                    this,
                    0,
                    resultIntent,
                    PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT
            );

    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new 
NotificationCompat.Builder(this, channelId)
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .setContentTitle("My notification")
            .setContentText("Hello World!")
            .setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent)
            ;

    // Gets an instance of the NotificationManager service
    NotificationManager mNotifyMgr =
            (NotificationManager) 
getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    mNotifyMgr.createNotificationChannel(mChannel);

    // Builds the notification and issues it.
    mNotifyMgr.notify(id, mBuilder.build());

}
```

**Update 1:**

I've changed String channelId = "name", but it still doesn't work. I even tried another set of code below, but still doesn't work:

```
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) 
getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        NotificationChannel notificationChannel = new 
NotificationChannel(NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID, "My Notifications", 
NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);

        // Configure the notification channel.
        notificationChannel.setDescription("Channel description");
        notificationChannel.enableLights(true);
        notificationChannel.setLightColor(Color.RED);
        notificationChannel.setVibrationPattern(new long[]{0, 1000, 500, 
1000});
        notificationChannel.enableVibration(true);
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel);
    }

    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new 
NotificationCompat.Builder(this, NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID)
            .setVibrate(new long[]{0, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100})

.setSound(RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION))
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .setContentTitle("Content Title")
            .setContentText("Content Text");

    notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, builder.build());
```

**Update 2:**

My build.gradle (project: test) as follows:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to 
all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {

repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0'


    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

My build.gradle (Module: app) is as follows:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.a0064274652969.test"
        minSdkVersion 26
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
}
```

Comment: Is an empty channelId valid? Try setting it to a value

Comment: Updated answer for your new code

Answer (score 1):

So I copied and pasted your original code and it runs fine (in emulator), meaning an empty string for the channelID is fine and so is zero for the notification id.

Your error is somewhere else, possibly in your devices android settings).
Try posting your build.gradle?

---

> If you target Android O and post a notification without specifying a
>   valid notifications channel, the notification fails to post and the
>   system logs an error.

For your new code, you're not setting the contentIntent anymore...also, do get a "Heads-up notification" you need to set the imporantce to HIGH or MAX.

Answer (score 0):

I'm finding the same issue and what worked for me was setting the builder priority as well as the notification priority. So adding this code should work for you.

```
    builder.setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_HIGH);
```